# Best practice with tag manager to duplicate tags across multiple subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up my website and it's subdomains with Google Analytics (UA) using Google Tag Manager.
I have a "master view/profile" which tracks traffic to all domains:
example.com
oranges.example.com
apples.example.com

I then have views set up for each subdomain, using rules I filter to only include traffic from URL hostname contains, e.g. oranges. for the subdomain oranges.example.com.

The master view contains lots of event tags, about 20 of them. I'd like to know events unique to each subdomain too. I could duplicate the existing tags and apply the duplicates to the same rule as oranges but that seems messy, especially when I in fact have about 5 subdomains and growing.

Is there a way to "share" the existing event tags on the master account to apply them to each subdomain view too?

This way I would have a master account with all traffic and events. I would also have specific subdomain views with traffic and events specific to each one.

Comment: You could adapt the method from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428814/setting-a-dynamic-macro-in-google-tag-manager/17443966#17443966 - fire the event tracking tag on both the domain and the subdomain and set the account id dynamically.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thanks I saw that post earlier. I tried something on the off chance it would work and it appears it has. In my "base" tag GAevents there is a field to enter UAID. The last digit I changed to [1-6] to cover each of my domains (they were are created under the same account so GA seems to increment them).